# Runtime error in crystal reports 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

When i try to run program (VS2010, .net4.0 full profile) that use Crystal reports 2010 in another computer from my develop machine, i get this error:

Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.

I try to google how to solve the problem, but editing config.app didnt work. My config.app:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings />
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/> 
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

The crystal reports got some problems here i think, when i try to run application with reports on another machine first time it didnt find crdb_adoplus.dll because it wasnt even exist in location that it should be. I have to create a new folder and copy some files from C:\Program Files\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet' to ...dotnet1. The error that i solved was:

I get this missing file error:"Could not load file or assembly file:///C:\Program Files\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet1\crdb_adoplus.dll or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

How to solve this? Thanks at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the version of asp.net from version 4 to version 2 in IIs...
try it

Comment: -its winforms application
-i need .net v4 because of my code, i use some new functions